# Position text on on tr line

Tags: html, css

There is a table with a few columns. The first column is `hours` and the rest of them are just empty.

The `hour` column has `label` in every fourth row. Every row should has exactly the same `height` and the label should be 'between rows' - the final result should looks like:
[image]

my code is:

```css
.headerClass {
  border: none;
}

.indexColumn {
  width: 30px;
  height: 10px;
}

.dataColumn {
  border-top: 2px solid #F5F5F5;
  border-left: 2px solid lightgrey;
  border-right: 2px solid lightgrey;
  width: 50px;
  height: 10px;
}

.startHour {
  border-top: 2px solid lightgrey;
  border-left: 2px solid lightgrey;
  border-right: 2px solid lightgrey;
}

table {
  border: none;
  border-collapse: collapse;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th class="headerClass  "></th>
      <th class="headerClass">first</th>
      <th class="headerClass">second</th>
      <th class="headerClass">third</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td class="">1:00</td>
      <td class="dataColumn startHour"></td>
      <td class="dataColumn startHour"></td>
      <td class="dataColumn startHour"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="indexColumn"></td>
      <td class="dataColumn"></td>
      <td class="dataColumn"></td>
      <td class="dataColumn"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="indexColumn"></td>
      <td class="dataColumn"></td>
      <td class="dataColumn"></td>
      <td class="dataColumn"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="indexColumn"></td>
      <td class="dataColumn"></td>
      <td class="dataColumn"></td>
      <td class="dataColumn"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="">2:00</td>
      <td class="dataColumn startHour"></td>
      <td class="dataColumn startHour"></td>
      <td class="dataColumn startHour"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="indexColumn"></td>
      <td class="dataColumn"></td>
      <td class="dataColumn"></td>
      <td class="dataColumn"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="indexColumn"></td>
      <td class="dataColumn"></td>
      <td class="dataColumn"></td>
      <td class="dataColumn"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="indexColumn"></td>
      <td class="dataColumn"></td>
      <td class="dataColumn"></td>
      <td class="dataColumn"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="">3:00</td>
      <td class="dataColumn startHour"></td>
      <td class="dataColumn startHour"></td>
      <td class="dataColumn startHour"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="indexColumn"></td>
      <td class="dataColumn"></td>
      <td class="dataColumn"></td>
      <td class="dataColumn"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="indexColumn"></td>
      <td class="dataColumn"></td>
      <td class="dataColumn"></td>
      <td class="dataColumn"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="indexColumn"></td>
      <td class="dataColumn"></td>
      <td class="dataColumn"></td>
      <td class="dataColumn"></td>
    </tr>
    <td class="">4:00</td>
    <td class="dataColumn startHour"></td>
    <td class="dataColumn startHour"></td>
    <td class="dataColumn startHour"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="indexColumn"></td>
      <td class="dataColumn"></td>
      <td class="dataColumn"></td>
      <td class="dataColumn"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="indexColumn"></td>
      <td class="dataColumn"></td>
      <td class="dataColumn"></td>
      <td class="dataColumn"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="indexColumn"></td>
      <td class="dataColumn"></td>
      <td class="dataColumn"></td>
      <td class="dataColumn"></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

the result is:
[image]

so the problem is that the `labels` changes the height of the rows in which they are placed and are not 'between them'.

How is it possible the get this effect? I tried to change the `margin-top` of `indexColumn` to `-15px` but nothing happend.

Comment: _"The hour column has label in every fourth row"_ I don't see this

Comment: @j08691 I mean that there is a `text`

Comment: Your row with 4:00 is missing an opening `<tr>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use positioning to move the hours up by 50% and to do that you'll need to wrap them in a an element, set its position to absolute, and set the position on the parent table cells to relative:

```css
.headerClass {
  border: none;
}

.indexColumn {
  width: 30px;
  height: 10px;
}

.dataColumn {
  border-top: 2px solid #F5F5F5;
  border-left: 2px solid lightgrey;
  border-right: 2px solid lightgrey;
  width: 50px;
  height: 10px;
}

.startHour {
  border-top: 2px solid lightgrey;
  border-left: 2px solid lightgrey;
  border-right: 2px solid lightgrey;
}

table {
  border: none;
  border-collapse: collapse;
}

td {
  position: relative;
}

span {
  top: -50%;
  position: absolute;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th class="headerClass  "></th>
      <th class="headerClass">first</th>
      <th class="headerClass">second</th>
      <th class="headerClass">third</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td class=""><span>1:00</span></td>
      <td class="dataColumn startHour"></td>
      <td class="dataColumn startHour"></td>
      <td class="dataColumn startHour"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="indexColumn"></td>
      <td class="dataColumn"></td>
      <td class="dataColumn"></td>
      <td class="dataColumn"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="indexColumn"></td>
      <td class="dataColumn"></td>
      <td class="dataColumn"></td>
      <td class="dataColumn"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="indexColumn"></td>
      <td class="dataColumn"></td>
      <td class="dataColumn"></td>
      <td class="dataColumn"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class=""><span>2:00</span></td>
      <td class="dataColumn startHour"></td>
      <td class="dataColumn startHour"></td>
      <td class="dataColumn startHour"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="indexColumn"></td>
      <td class="dataColumn"></td>
      <td class="dataColumn"></td>
      <td class="dataColumn"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="indexColumn"></td>
      <td class="dataColumn"></td>
      <td class="dataColumn"></td>
      <td class="dataColumn"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="indexColumn"></td>
      <td class="dataColumn"></td>
      <td class="dataColumn"></td>
      <td class="dataColumn"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class=""><span>3:00</span></td>
      <td class="dataColumn startHour"></td>
      <td class="dataColumn startHour"></td>
      <td class="dataColumn startHour"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="indexColumn"></td>
      <td class="dataColumn"></td>
      <td class="dataColumn"></td>
      <td class="dataColumn"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="indexColumn"></td>
      <td class="dataColumn"></td>
      <td class="dataColumn"></td>
      <td class="dataColumn"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="indexColumn"></td>
      <td class="dataColumn"></td>
      <td class="dataColumn"></td>
      <td class="dataColumn"></td>
    </tr>
    <td class=""><span>4:00</span></td>
    <td class="dataColumn startHour"></td>
    <td class="dataColumn startHour"></td>
    <td class="dataColumn startHour"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="indexColumn"></td>
      <td class="dataColumn"></td>
      <td class="dataColumn"></td>
      <td class="dataColumn"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="indexColumn"></td>
      <td class="dataColumn"></td>
      <td class="dataColumn"></td>
      <td class="dataColumn"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="indexColumn"></td>
      <td class="dataColumn"></td>
      <td class="dataColumn"></td>
      <td class="dataColumn"></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `rowspan="2"` on hour `<td>`

Comment: I'd like to add that he need to remove the first TD on the next row too.

Answer (score 0):

You can set the line-height of the text in td:

```
td {
  line-height: 12px;
}
```

12px because it's the height (10px) plus the border (2px)!

Answer (score 0):

One solution is to use absolute positioning:

Change

```
 <td class="">4:00</td>
```

to

```
 <td style="position:relative"><span style="position:absolute; top:0">4:00</span></td>
```

Answer (score 0):

Make a class for hours too and set the font size same as height.

```
<td class="hourColumn">1:00</td>


<style>
 .hourColumn{
        height: 10px;
        font-size: 8px;
    }
</style>
```